# Add a strong name to an external library coming from Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, strongname

We have a project for which we have to provide Strong name for the DLL(Not really my choice but I've to deal with it).

We are referencing some Nuget packages, and one of them doesn't have a strong name. I know it is possible to sign ourself a DLL, but I can't find how/if there is a way to do this when using nuget.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just strong name sign the dlls you want to package, and simply pack them into a nupkg as you normally would....you don't sign the nupkg itself.

Comment: dear downvoter, can you tell me what about the answer do you not agree with? That would be really helpful to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no straight answer to that. Either you need to ask the nuget package author to update the package with strong name dlls or you would need to find another package that does the job for you and has strong name dlls.